# Create auto hot key script that copies file paths onto clipboard as python styled list

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to create an autohotkey script that produces a python styled list when copying multiple filepaths in explorer.

E.g If I had three files within the C directory like below:
[image]

Then pressing the ahk shortcut should copy the following paths to my clipboard in the below style:

```
["C:\a.txt","C:\b.txt","C:\c.txt"]
```

However if a single filepath is selected I'd prefer for it to remain in a string format when copied onto the clipboard e.g copying 'a.txt' should copy the path to my clipboard as:

`"C:\a.txt"`

I've tried to generate my own ahk shortcut but keep getting errors when I try to manipulate the clipboard:

```
#c::
    Send ^c
    ClipWait
    Clipboard:= Clipboard ""
    temp := Clipboard
    paths := StrSplit(temp, "`r`n")

    num_paths := paths.MaxIndex()
    if (num_paths == 1)
    {
        Clipboard:= `".Clipboard.`"
        Return
    }
    

    Array := []
    For path in paths
    {
        path := `".path.`"
        Array.push(path)
    }
    Clipboard:= Array ""
Return
```

Any help fixing this shortcut would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
#c::
    Send ^c
    Email
    Email:= Email ""
    temp := Email
    paths := StrSplit(temp, "`r`n")

    num_paths := paths.MaxIndex()
    if (num_paths == 1)
    {
        Email:= `".Email.`"
        Return
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing but unfortunately that didn't fix my issue. I managed to resolve it on my own but thanks for your help in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Had to read up a bit on ahk syntax but I figured it out in the end.
Here's my working shortcut:

```
#c:: 
    Clipboard := ""
    Send, ^c 
    ClipWait , 2
    Clipboard:= Clipboard . ""
    temp := Clipboard
    paths := StrSplit(temp, "`r`n")

    num_paths := paths.MaxIndex()
    if (num_paths == 1)
    {
        Clipboard:= "'" . temp . "'"
        Return
    }

    output_string := "["
    For key,path in paths
    {
        path := "'" . path . "'"
        output_string := output_string . path . ", "
    }
    StringTrimRight, output_string, output_string, 2
    output_string := output_string . "]"
    Clipboard:= output_string
Return
```